# An error in Python: Token Error: EOF in multi-line statement

Tags: python

I keep getting this error in python. Can anyone ask me what this means and what I have to do to fix this. 
Here is my code:

```
def choice():
    userChoice = str(raw_input("Enter your choice. E or D: ")
    if userChoice == "e" or "d":
        return userChoice
    else:
        print("Invalid Choice. Please try again.")
choice()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a closing paren:

```
userChoice = str(raw_input("Enter your choice. E or D: ") <-
```

Also you if should be:

```
if userChoice == "e" or  userChoice == "d":
```

Or use in:

```
if userChoice in {"e","d"}
```

`or "d"` will always evaluate to True as any non empty string will evaluate to True.

`raw_input` is also already a string so the str call is redundant.

Also if you want to keep asking use a while True loop:

```
def choice():
    while True:
        user_choice = raw_input("Enter your choice. E or D: ").lower()
        if user_choice in {"e", "d"}:
            return user_choice
        print("Invalid Choice. Please try again.")
```

Answer (score -2):

Corrected code:

```
def choice():
userChoice = str(raw_input("Enter your choice. E or D: "))
    if set(userChoice.lower()) in set('ed'):
        return userChoice
    else:
        print("Invalid Choice. Please try again.")
choice()
```

Explanation:

- Set used on string returns you all unique characters used in string, using parameter 'in' on sets checks if first one is inside another (all elements from set one are in set two)
- Lower is used in case user mistakes big case letter with lower case